# When must a specific product map exist?

Tags: category-theory, products, limits-colimits

Suppose that it's *unknown* whether a category $\mathcal{C}$ contains all products, but that it happens to have the products $a\times b$ and $c\times d$. Further, $\mathcal{C}$ has morphisms $f:a\rightarrow c$ and $g:b\rightarrow d$. In what situations must the product map $f\times g$ exist? (Or something isomorphic to it, since we aren't necessarily dealing with pointwise functions.)

Since $\{f\circ \pi_a:a\times b\rightarrow c,g\circ \pi_b:a\times b\rightarrow d\}$ is a cone over $\{c,d\}$, some $h:a\times b\rightarrow c\times d$ must exist as a factorization through $c\times d$, i.e., $f\circ \pi_a=\pi_c\circ h$ and $g\circ \pi_b=\pi_d\circ h$. But does this mean that $h\cong f\times g$?

As a special case, suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object $1$, the products $1\times 1$ (not necessarily terminal) and $a\times b$, and element selectors $x:1\rightarrowtail a$ and $y:1\rightarrowtail b$. When must $x\times y$ exist (up to isomorphism)? Stated colloquially: In what situations can you construct an element selector for a product by combining element selectors for its constituent objects?

*Motivation: My intuition for set products has long been that you can construct an element by selecting one element from each constituent set. I've recently realized, however, that elements of non-set products might not be **constructible from** smaller parts. The categorical definition only requires that they can be **projected onto** their constituent objects.*

Comment: The product map $f\times g$ exists as soon as the two products exist, as your construction shows.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm not fully convinced. The limit is defined entirely in terms of commutativity, so it seems like $h$ and $f\times g$ could differ non-trivially, but in ways that ultimately don't matter for the purposes of commutativity. For example, maybe $f$ and $g$ are monic but $h$ isn't.

Comment: $h$ and $f\times g$ cannot differ in any way, since they must be equal... Don't forget the uniqueness requirement in the definition of the product/limit !

Comment: Your construction of $h$ is usually taken to be the definition of $f\times g$ in an abstract category where the required products exist. Also, so far you've only posited a 1-category, so without further clarification it's not obvious how to interpret two morphisms being isomorphic.

Comment: Moreover, whenever a terminal object $1$ exists, the product $1\times 1$ necessarily exists and is also terminal. Provided $a\times b$ exists, so does the morphism $x\times y$, and this is a special case of the construction of $h=f\times g$ you exhibited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments lay out, $f\times g$ exists and is given by your $h$ once $a\times b$ and $c\times d$ exist.
To see this, it's important to first understand what $f\times g$ means.

Given $f:a\to c$ and $g:b\to d$, the product $f\times g$ should map $a\times b\to c\times d$ in a way that resembles "acting by $f$ on $a$ and acting by $g$ on $b$ and then combining them."
In categorical language, this means exactly that $\pi_c(f\times g)=f\pi_a$ and $\pi_d(f\times g)=g\pi_b$.

Let's return to your $h$. You've shown that once $a\times b$ and $c\times d$ exist, then there is a map $h:a\times b\to c\times d$ with the same property that $\pi_ch=f\pi_a$ and $\pi_dh=g\pi_b$.
The key here is that since $h$ was defined by the universal property of $c\times d$, it is *unique* with this property, and this uniqueness forces that $f\times g=h$. In other words, your construction describes *precisely* how to obtain $f\times g$ from $f$ and $g$.

In your special case where $a=b=1$, this shows that the answer is **always**! In fact, since $1\times1=1$ (check universal properties), the resulting map $x\times y:1\times 1\to c\times d$ corresponds exactly to the tuple $(x,y):1\to c\times d$ obtained from the universal property of $c\times d$.

---

To address your motivation: you actually can construct products in an arbitrary category by combining its constituent "elements" once you establish what "elements" means. From the perspective of the Yoneda embedding, you can equivalently think of an object $a$ of a (locally small) category as a family of sets $(a_s)_s$ indexed by the category, where $a_s$ is the set of "$s$-shaped elements in $a$"; that is, morphisms $s\to a$. (These elements are then subject to compatibility constraints which just say that $s\mapsto a_s$ is a presheaf, since this is really the representable functor $\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom(-,a)$).

What is a product from this perspective? Given two objects $a$ and $b$, the product $a\times b$ should be the collection of pairs of elements of $a$ and $b$: in other words, we would want $(a\times b)_s = a_s\times b_s$, the right hand side being the usual Cartesian product of sets.
If the product $a\times b$ exists, then this is indeed true by the universal property of the product! (In fact, this could be seen as a way of *motivating* the universal property definition.) Indeed, it says that for any $s$-shaped elements $x:s\to a$ and $y:s\to b$, there must be a unique corresponding element $(x,y):s\to a\times b$.

This is also a way of making sense of the statement that "$a\times b$ is, when it exists, the representing object of the presheaf $\Hom(-,a)\times\Hom(-,b)$."

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Just to clarify my understanding, how do we know that $1\rightarrow 1\times 1$ exists, or even that $1\times 1$ is the codomain of anything besides $id_{1\times 1}$? Is it because the two projections from $1\times 1\rightarrow 1$ must be equal, thereby implying that they're both $id_1$?

Comment: $1\to1\times1$ is the diagonal map (induced by the identity on $1$ paired with itself), and yeah composing this with either projection results in the unique map $1\to1$ (that is, the identity), and $1\times1$ and $1$ are thus uniquely isomorphic